# Make column readonly on specific condition oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create some kind of trigger to prevent a row being edited if it is after today's date (will use SYSDATE to get that).

I am unsure about how to do this as I am new to PL/SQL and would think perhaps some kind of package that gets the date using a cursor then uses a function to return a boolean to a procedure which then somehow stops the DML statement from firing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you need a date column as your target.  Truncating SYSDATE will give you midnight.  Consequently if a truncated SYSDATE is greater than another date it must be at least the next day.

Raising an application error will cause the update to fail.  Note that if you're updating multiple rows a single failure will rollback all the changes.

```
create or replace trigger your_trg 
    before update on your_table 
    for each row 
begin
    if trunc(sysdate) > :old.whatever_date then
        raise_application_error(-20000, 'It is too late to change this record');
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply I keep getting

 ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification

Im not sure what is the problem with the syntax

UPDATE: for some reason oracle did not like the 'AS' keyword

Comment: Ooops, remove the AS and try again

Answer (score 0):

the solution you are looking for is [VPD Column masking](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/vpd.htm#i1014682). 
mainly used for security purposes, VPD enables you to define row/colums level rules for data access and display.